# ESSBASE @FIX statement

Tags: scripting, essbase

I am trying to learn essbase scripting on my own and came across the following parts in a big script.

```
    fix ("Stock Alloc %");
        @idescendants("Company A");
    endfix;
```

I think this part is doing nothing because

fix ("Stock Alloc %") is just selecting "Stock Alloc %" member 
and 
@idescendants("Company A"); is just listing out all the descendants of "Company A" including itself.

So nothing really is happening. Am I correct ?

I understand this is a very trivial question but I do not have anyone to ask/clarify.

It would be very kind of someone to comment. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right that nothing is happening. For starters, it is customary to not put semi-colons after the FIX or ENDFIX, as well as customary to capitalize keywords ("FIX ("Stock Alloc %")). Finally, the reason nothing seems to happen is because you aren't actually calculating anything. You either need a CALC inside of the FIX or you need to assign a value to something, such as by setting it with DATACOPY or a equals statement.

Comment: It appears you may want to calculate the Company A hierarchy, in that case you may want to FIX (@IDESCENDANTS("Company A")) and then CALC DIM on some other dimension. Be sure to check out the examples for Sample.Basic in the reference.